# Converting ascii text to to number and back to ascii

Tags: python, ascii

I am creating a python code which has two functions

- textToNumber(t)
- numberToText(n)

---

textToNumber(t) function takes a plain text parameter ('Hello world') and converts it to a very big number by considering ASCII values of each letter. The function looks like this:

```
def textToNumber (txt):
  text_number = 0
  for letter in txt:
    text_number = (text_number * 256) + ord(letter)
  return text_number
```

---

numberToText(n) takes a number and converts it to its corresponding plain text. This function is exactly opposite to the first function. It looks like this:

```
def numberToText (nm):
  n = nm
  number_text = ""
  while n > 0:
    part_n = int(n) & 255
    number_text = chr(part_n) + number_text
    n = n - part_n
    n = n / 256
  return number_text
```

---

So, when we use the second function within the first, it should give us the original text back. The function works fine with a small text, but gives gibberish when the text is big. I think Python has no constraint over the size of variables as long as our machine has the space. So, why does this happen? How do I solve it?

Error output:

```
>>> numberToText(textToNumber('Hello world'))
'Hello x\x00\x00\x00d'
```

Comment: Use `//` instead of `/` to get integer division.

Comment: Otherwise you get floating point numbers, and they don't have as much precision as large integers.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! That was a very easy fix. I want this for implementing RSA algorithm on the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `//` instead of `/` to get integer division.
Otherwise you get floating point numbers, and they don't have as much precision as large integers.